# Sorting a hasMany relationship without an ArrayController

Tags: javascript, sorting, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to figure out the "Ember way" to do a sort when you don't have an array controller to rely on.

I created a jsbin to explain the situation, <strike>though I wasn't able to get it work on the jsbin (though it works in my project): http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mused/2/edit?html,js</strike>

**FIX** -- Thanks to kingpin, this jsbin is working: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/quyawitu/5/edit

Basically, say you have two models: "House" and "Window"

A house hasMany windows. A window belongsTo a house.

Now say you are in a template that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each house in model}}
      <li>
        <div class="name">
          House name: {{house.name}}
        </div>
        <div>
          First Window: {{house.firstWindow}}
        </div>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

In this template, I am not interested in just linking to an association to windows -- instead, I am looking for the first window (specifically, the first window, sorted by createdAt).

Using the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601092/ember-js-sorting-and-filtering-children-of-a-hasmany-relationship-in-parent-rout), I used an ArrayProxy with the sortable mixin to create a computed property on my House model to get this reference. I am wondering if there is a more idiomatic "Ember way" to do this.

Answer (score 1):

upgrade ember and use the built in `sortBy`

In your particular case, since you've switched to the fixture adapter, those items are async, so I had to change a few of those things to make it work in your jsbin

```
  firstWindow: function(){
    return this.get('windowsByCreatedAt.firstObject');
  }.property('windowsByCreatedAt.firstObject'),

  windowsByCreatedAt: function() {
    var arr = [];
    this.get('windows').then(function(windows){
      arr.pushObjects(windows.sortBy('createdAt'));
    });
    return arr;
  }.property('windows.@each.createdAt')
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/quyawitu/3/edit

Or if you want to watch the `isLoaded` and repopulate the computed property it looks a lot cleaner:

```
  windowsByCreatedAt: function() {
    return this.get('windows').sortBy('createdAt');
  }.property('windows.@each.createdAt', 'windows.isLoaded')
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/quyawitu/6/edit

Comment: I used a jsbin template and it must have been more out of date then I thought-- Thanks for fixing that!


I feel like the 'windowsByCreatedAt' function still feels a little clunky to me. It's not too different then using the sortable mixin on an array proxy -- here is a jsbin for it: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/quyawitu/5/edit. I am probably just assuming there should be a perfect, pretty solution to this problem when there isn't.

Comment: it's mostly clunky due to the fact that windows needed to be async in that particular situation, I'll toss up the lazy approach to waiting on async updates.

Comment: And the only reason I call it lazy, is because I prefer to use the promise, but it's still valid and doesn't crash this situation (firstWindow is undefined momentarily, but no issue to the template)

Comment: Right, I see. That does look great. Does sortBy have a flag for ascending or descending?

Comment: no, I think a few PRs are floating around for that, it's defaults implementation allowed multiple items to be sent in at once, but didn't allow asc/desc.  In the case of a single sort, reverse is plausible alternative.