# Ember sorting hasMany relationship

Tags: javascript, sorting, ember.js

I'd like to sort a set of categories and items in ascending order (A-Z).

My HBS template iterates over an {{each}} category, and then over {{each}} item inside the category.

I've tried to pass sortProperties to each array controller, but this doesn't seem to affect anything. I also tried to extract the sorting to an array proxy (using help from here: [Ember.js sorting and filtering children of a hasMany relationship in parent route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601092/ember-js-sorting-and-filtering-children-of-a-hasmany-relationship-in-parent-rout))

Any ideas how to go forward from here?

Here's my JSBin so far: http://jsbin.com/momihe/8/edit

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would be to just sort the items on the model, then iterate over them

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr("string"),
    createdAt: DS.attr('date', { defaultValue: new Date() }),
    items: DS.hasMany('item', { async: true }),
    sortedItems: Em.computed.sort('items', function(item1, item2){    
      return item1.get('desc').localeCompare(item2.get('desc'));
    })
});
```

http://jsbin.com/lojep/1/edit

The next easiest is to use an item controller, and put the sorted list on there

#### Template

```
 {{#each model itemController='foo'}}
    <li><strong>{{title}}</strong>
      {{#each sortedItems}}
        <div>{{desc}}</div>
      {{/each}}
      <br>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
```

#### Controller

```
App.FooController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  sortedItems: Em.computed.sort('items', function(item1, item2){    
    return item1.get('desc').localeCompare(item2.get('desc'));
  })
});
```

http://jsbin.com/lojep/2/edit

Comment: This is great, thanks! I'll use option 2 since it seems like sorting is more of a decorative function, and should probably not reside in the model.